# When/how are Constraints Checked in a SqlBulkCopy w/ Check Constraints enabled?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sqlbulkcopy

I am performing several `SqlBulkCopy`'s in a single transaction, I need to be able to roll back easily if anything goes wrong. I'm bulk copying several tables that have foreign keys to each other. I want these constraints checked. I'm copying the parent table first, then the child tables, but I'm receiving foreign key constraint errors. Does `SqlBulkCopy` include the rows inserted in the transaction when checking constraints?

Comment: You lost me with this question - `Does SqlBulkCopy include the rows inserted in the transaction when checking constraints?`.

Comment: In the first SqlBulkCopy I insert several rows in a different table. Are these new rows used when checking the constraints for the next insert, despite being in the same transaction?

Answer (score 4):

[By default constraints are not checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions(v=vs.110).aspx). Change the options of the SqlBulkCopy to check them during insertion.

> Check constraints while data is being inserted. By default,
>   constraints are not checked